# multiple like on same column and give first prority which satisfy maximum or condition

Tags: sql

The query is something like this:

```
select title from sample where
  title like '%php%' or 
  title like '%html%' or
  title like '%css%' or
  title like '%javascript%'
```

I want to order records by number of conditions that they match.

Comment: What database are you using?  I'm removing the extraneous tags (leaving sql).  Add the *one* database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by including the conditions in the `order by` as well as the `where`:

```
select title
from sample
where title like '%php%' or 
      title like '%html%' or
      title like '%css%' or
      title like '%javascript%'
order by ((title like '%php%') + 
          (title like '%html%') +
          (title like '%css%') +
          (title like '%javascript%')) desc;
```

In an numeric context (such as `+`), MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

For databases other than MySQL, use a `case` statement:

```
order by ((case when title like '%php%' then 1 else 0 end) + 
          (case when title like '%html%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when title like '%css%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when title like '%javascript%' then 1 else 0 end)) desc;
```